# Looping through one column and check for values except initial

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Yesterday I asked a question about checking for values in column A. I got some good answers, but it was based on that the values i checked for were next to each other in the column such as, D3874 BGE XS, I3874 BGE XS in the column under with values such as,

D3875 HMG XS

D3875 BGE XS

D3874 BGE XS

I3874 BGE XS

After som testing it seems that i need to approach this problem from a new angle.

My column did in also have rows that looked like,

D3875 HMG XS

D3840 BGE XS

D3871 BGE XS

I3875 BGE XS

I3875 HMG XS

SO wath i am trying to do is write a loop that took the value next to I or D in the rows, like 3875 and then i would like to run this trough the column until i find the same value exept an I instead of D in the beginning and then print decided next to the first value.

Basically what i want my code to do is to check the 4 digit number after I or D and se if there is cell with the same 4 digit number but an I instead of D in the beginning. It it checks cell D3875 HMG XS i want to use nr 3875 to see if i can find a cell with value I3875.

My code right know is this but my skills has reached it peak (6 hours in) and i cant get it to work.

```
Sub leta_PU()

Dim dataworksheet As Worksheet
Dim leta As String
Dim name As String
Dim flik As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set dataworksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim Project3 As String
Dim Project1 As String
Dim Project2 As String

 Set flik = dataworksheet

 leta = dataworksheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
 Project1 = Left(leta, 5)
 Project2 = Right(milsten1, 4)
  Project3 = "I" & Project2
  Debug.Print (Project3)

  Dim statuskolumn As Long

  statuskolumn = rowNRAMTstatus(Project3, flik)
   Debug.Print ("Statuskolumn= " & statuskolumn)

   Dim dagensstatus As Variant
   dagensstatus = dataworksheet.Cells(rad, statuskolumn).Value                               leveranssheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = dagensstatus 

                    If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 2).Value >= 1 Then
                    leveranssheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Decided"
                Else
                    leveranssheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Not Decided"

               End If
```

End Sub

My function rowNRAMTstatus that i would like to check values in column A are,

```
 Function rowNRASMTstatus(namn As String, sourceWS As Worksheet) As Integer


Dim antalrader As Integer
Dim rad As Integer
Dim rowname As String
Dim lstrow As ListColumn

'Debug.Print 
With sourceWS

    antalrader = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To antalrader
        Set lstrow = .Cells(1, i)
            rowname = lstrow.Value
            'Debug.Print (rowname)
        If rowname Like namn & "*" & "U" Then ' If kolname = "*" & namn Then
            Debug.Print ("Får träff på kolumnnamn " & namn & " i kolumn " & kolname)
            rad = i
            'Debug.Print ("Som har nr " & kolumn)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i

End With
  rowNRASMTstatus = rad
  'Debug.Print (kolumnNR)


 End Function
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? You'll be much more likely to get a good answer if you describe what the result should be.  As it stands, the question is basically "this code doesn't work" and "checking for values" could mean anything.

Comment: Fair enough! I edit my post with an deeper description of what i actually wants! Thanks for the input Comintern!

Comment: I don't understand.  This is what I think you want - if you go down column "L" - for example, you want to get the four numeric numbers from each cell, and then search another column for that same number - and "IF" the original cell starts with the letter "D" - AND the searched cell begins with the letter "I" - then you want to put the word "Decided" into the cell just to the right of the searched cell?  Is that about it?

Comment: Thats correct John Muggins but its just one column. To copy that column to another column if its easier its not a problem altough. But in my case its just alot of rows with cell values in column A.

Comment: What about a formula like `=IF(AND(LEFT(A2)="D", ISNUMBER(MATCH("I"&MID(A2, 2, 4)&"*",A:A, 0))), "decided", "")` ?

Comment: THat worked! WOW. How did u learn to make these formulas?? And how do i give credit to u Jeeped?

Answer (score 0):

Jeeped solved this problem with style!!

What about a formula like =IF(AND(LEFT(A2)="D", ISNUMBER(MATCH("I"&MID(A2, 2, 4)&"*",A:A, 0))), "decided", "") ? – Jeeped 15 hours ago